# Grid Height Issue between divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created div grid system with HTML and CSS using the float:left method.

It works fine, however whenever there is a variable height difference between two divs in the same row, the next div starts at the bottom most position just below the div that has the greatest height.

Here's the codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJZWoX

CSS:

```
.parent{
  width:330px;
}

.red{
  float:left;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  margin-left:10px;
  background-color:red;
}

.blue{
  float:left;
  width:150px;
  height:300px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  margin-left:10px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

Is there a way to solve this error using just css? Any good answer would be appreciated.

This is what I'm looking for:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: I would read up on Flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Doing this in only CSS will make it a very tough task, there are some excellent plug ins that can help you though. Perhaps you would like something along the lines of **[masonry.js](http://masonry.desandro.com/)**, this is not mine but here is an excellent **[example](http://codepen.io/seanmccaffery/pen/Gxtqy)** of how masonry.js works.

Comment: Not with just CSS, only with flexbox. See my answer. @Earthling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just CSS? With flexbox you could http://demosthenes.info/blog/844/Easy-Masonry-Layout-With-Flexbox

But I would opt for Javascript as a more robust (and slightly better browser support at the time of posting) approach.

via JQuery Masonry http://masonry.desandro.com/ (supported from IE9+)